# Data within table does show up angular 2 primeng

Tags: primeng-datatable

I am going through a angular2 source where data are shown in a table with the help of primeng, and I am going through the following issue:

1. When I click on the link for the firt time, the page display that "No records found".
2. Then I check if data is actually loaded into the memory or not, and it is validated that the data is loaded, but is not shown in the table with the initial load.

I have the following properties set to the p-dataTable:

1. ## dt [value]="entries" [paginator]="true" [pagelinks]="3" [rowsPerPageOptions]=[5,10,20]

When I click and choose either 5, or 10, or 20 from the combo, I can see the table.

So the issue is is that when the page is loaded initially, the data is not shown in the table, even after "5" is shown on the combo for [rowsPerPageOptions]. I expect to see 5 rows in the table.

Any idea to get around with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data is not loaded until you will not bind data with the row.

Please try like this :[rows]="5"

Ex:
dt [value]="entries" [paginator]="true" [pagelinks]="3" [rows]="5" [rowsPerPageOptions]=[5,10,20]

Comment: Has the same issue. When adding [rows]="5" i can see the data for 5 rows only, however when pressing the "next" button all the data is loaded to the table and not just the next 5 that are defined by [rowsPerPageOptions]. Any idea how to overcome this issue?